# show a div while hidding another with ng hide and ng show

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a button that when clicked makes a div disappear with ng-hide but i cant figure out how i can make the other div appear when i click that button. Right now my code is this:

```html
<div class="col text-center"><button class="button b3" ng-click="goEsconder = !goEsconder">
     Ver fotos
   </button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" ng-hide="goEsconder">
    <div class="col tipo"><p class="tip">Tipo de espaço:</p><p class="tip2">Escritório</p>
    <p class="tip">Preço:</p><p class="tip2">{{detalhes[1]}}€/mês</p>

    <div class="col tipo"><p class="tip">Condições:</p>
    <p class="tip2">150 m2 de espaço
configurável</p>
</div>
```

My controller

```js
.controller('perfilCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', "detailService",// The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams, detailService) {
$scope.detalhes=detailService.data;
$scope.goEsconder = false;
}])
```

And i want this div to show when the button is clicked and the other div hides

```html
  <div class="imagem">
   <img ng-src="http://www.comoditamodulados.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/executivo_-300x300.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
  </div>
```

Comment: You can use multiple `ng-hide` in your code on a single variable

Comment: Just add `ng-show="goEsconder"` to the div and you should be set.

Comment: Well, that was easy ahah Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="imagem" ng-hide="!goEsconder">
   <img ng-src="http://www.comoditamodulados.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/executivo_-300x300.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
  </div>
```

Or as @Adwaenyth mentioned.

```
<div class="imagem" ng-show="goEsconder">
   <img ng-src="http://www.comoditamodulados.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/executivo_-300x300.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
  </div>
```